# Website folders do not have full SSL lock

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, cloudflare

So I am making a new website, [Link](http://qualexcraft.tk), but for some reason no folders have the full SSL icon. The top-level index.php file has the lock, but anything inside a folder, try /blog, has partial-ssl. It has the lock, but hides it because of the "Someone can change the look of this page" type error. Please help, as I do not know why this is hapenning. I do use cloudflare, and have set a http://qualexcraft.tk/* page rule to force https.

UPDATE: Now no folders or files have the full lock

For anyone interested, here is my htaccess file:

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 http://qualexcraft.tk/404
# Redirect www urls to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.qualexcraft\.tk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://qualexcraft.tk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Directory Structure:**

index.php

404

```
index.php

old.php
```

assets

```
images
```

blog

```
allPosts

index.php
```

includes

```
headers

  head.html

  index.html

layout

  footer.html

  navbar.html
```

maps

mdl

```
[mdl files]
```

Comment: Not a lot of links in your page... but it's ok with `/mdl/material.min.js`...

Comment: In your `blog`page: `http://placehold.it/512x176` change that, with `https`or `//placehold.it/512x176`

Comment: Try /blog, it doesnt work, on Chrome atleast

Comment: Ok, lemme try that. Thing is, it didn't work before putting the placeholder either. My second editor JUST put that in. Try my /404 folder, no full SSL, has the "people can change the content" type thing.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Any Thoughts?

Comment: The problem is in the content, not in the SSL configuration. That work well with `/mdl/` folder

Comment: Now it's ok with your `blog` page !

Comment: Still not for me. It still has partial (on Chrome)

Comment: With Chrome, you have the same problem with your root page... (it's in the content, not in the SSL configuration...)

Comment: On Chrome, the root page works perfectly, anything else is broken

Comment: Not from here... (Chome version...)

Comment: Hmmm....strange. Will upload screenshots tomorrow. Have to go.

Comment: So I was on it again. The root (index.php) has the lock, but ANYTHING else has the lock, but it quickly disappears and shows the "secured but people can change the look of this page". I opened up the console and saw it saying this. Strange message incoming...."Mixed Content: The page at 'https://qualexcraft.tk/blog/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://qualexcraft.tk/404/'. This content should also be served over HTTPS."

Comment: Another strange thing is that it displays this twice

Comment: Answer in the question... change `ErrorDocument 404 https://qualexcraft.tk/404` or `ErrorDocument 404 /404`

Comment: First, resolve your ssl problem, and try only with pages without content (only "Hello" in <body>). After that try with content, and when you see the problem again it's with your last add...

Comment: How should I change my ErrorDocument. If I do /404 it doesnt work for reason, and because it "doesnt exist" it loops. This isn't an ordinary issue, and is quite weird.

Comment: For instance, why doesnt /mdl work, its a folder with no content, but it doesnt have the lock (same error as above)

Comment: Do you have some other rules? Either in subsequent htaccess or the server config (or vhosts config) files?

Comment: @hjpotter92 No, that is my entire and only htaccess. I don't have any vhost configs either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the reasons for the bahaviour is the following line in your htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://qualexcraft.tk/404
```

When the client requests for the image `https://qualexcraft.tk/blog/images/android-desktop.png`, a **302** redirection to `http://qualexcraft.tk/404` is triggered. This page, in turn, has a permanent redirection set to `https://qualexcraft.tk/404`.

Now, as I asked [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614538/website-folders-do-not-have-full-ssl-lock#comment55150493_33614538), there is another rule which adds a trailing `/` in the URLs and redirects it to `http://qualexcraft.tk/404/`. This, lastly; redirects with the status code **301** to the secure page: `https://qualexcraft.tk/404/`.

The intermediate redirects to `http` pages is the root cause of your problem. The same occurs when someone visits the `blog` link on your website.

The request to `https://qualexcraft.tk/blog` gets redirected to `http://qualexcraft.tk/blog/` and then to `https://qualexcraft.tk/blog/`.

---

After your changes to the website, the behaviour is still the same, except that the request is now for `https://qualexcraft.tk/favicon.ico`.

---

Try updating your htaccess to the following:

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectorySlash Off
ErrorDocument 404 https://qualexcraft.tk/404

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.qualexcraft\.tk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://qualexcraft.tk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yeah, I observed the same behavior with the 404s when monitoring my network traffic in chrome. There were some 404s aimed at `http` rather than `https` during the redirects. @Philippos Slicher Try removing the `<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/android-desktop.png">` code from your page, and the lock icon should return. If this fixes it, the 404-related suggestions in the above post should fix the problem. Make sure to clear your cache due to the caching nature of 301 redirects.

Comment: Ok I'm trying that right now. I am adding an image rather than removing the line though.

Comment: @hjpotter92 So what exactly do I need to do?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Wait where did you see the /blog/images/........It should be /images/android......

Comment: @PhilipposSlicher Updated the post above. Please check

Comment: @hjpotter92 I never had a resource link to the favicon though. apache searches for favicon in root by default. Also, I want to have trailing slashes on

Comment: @hjpotter92 If I disable trailing slashes, it breaks directories and shows the files in the directory, not the index file in the dir. And if I re enable, the lock breaks again.

Comment: @PhilipposSlicher Is the server on shared hosting, or do you have access to server config? Or the access to server logs?

Comment: It is on shared. I don't have access to config or logs

Comment: Ok. @PhilipposSlicher Can you add the directory structure of your website? (include upto `index` files).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95035/discussion-between-philippos-slicher-and-hjpotter92).

Answer (score -1):

Add your favicon image to favicon.ico, to images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png and to images/android-desktop.png. That is the only insecure content error that can be seen so once that is fixed you should be okay after clearing your browser cache.

In order to spot mixed content errors in the future, you can go to the console in Chrome (right click > Inspect Element > console) and your insecure content errors will be displayed there.

Comment: Yes, I know about the console part, but the strange thing is it says "Insecure favicon: qualexcraft.tk/404"

Comment: Could you explain? Read above. Sorry for duplicates, didn't ping